# Looping through number of types

Tags: c++, loops

Suppose I want test something with `vector<int>`, `vector<bool>`, `vector<string>`. I want to write something like this:

```
for(type T in {int, bool, string}){
   vector<T> v;
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
       v.push_back(randomValue<T>());
   }
   assert(v.size() == 3);
}
```

I know there isn't such feature in the language but is it possible to emulate somehow? Is there this functional in some library, for example `boost`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Boost.MPL

It is possible to accomplish with **typelists** - they are discussed in details in [Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315) by **Andrei Alexandrescu**

Check [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) library. For instance - [boost::mpl::for_each](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html)

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d04811e4d202af51)

```
#include <boost/exception/detail/type_info.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T randomValue()
{
    return T();
}

struct Benchmark
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T) const
    {
        cout << "Testing " << type_name<T>() << endl;
        vector<T> v;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
           v.push_back(randomValue<T>());
        }
        assert(v.size() == 3);
    }
};

int main()
{
    mpl::for_each<mpl::vector<int, bool, string>>(Benchmark());
}
```

Output is:

```
Testing int
Testing bool
Testing std::string
```

---

## C++11 Variadic Templates

Another option is to use C++11 variadic templates:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/351cbd14ded56f5c)

```
#include <boost/exception/detail/type_info.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T randomValue()
{
    return T();
}

struct Benchmark
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T) const
    {
        cout << "Testing " << type_name<T>() << endl;
        vector<T> v;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
           v.push_back(randomValue<T>());
        }
        assert(v.size() == 3);
    }
};

template<typename ...Ts,typename F>
void for_each(F f)
{
    auto &&t = {(f(Ts()),0)...};
    (void)t;
}

int main()
{
    for_each<int, bool, string>(Benchmark());
}
```

Comment: BOOST.MPL is absolutely enough for me, but 1 problem that could be intresting: it [doesn't work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2TZHbN$4) with not default constructable types(if I test it correctly)

Comment: In such case, fast solution is just to [use pointers](http://liveworkspace.org/code/sChpB$0)

Comment: Does this cause the constructors of the vector elements to be called? @EvgenyPanasyuk: Your link doesn't work for me. I suppose you're talking about the same problem and proposed calling with pointer types instead?

Comment: @Syncopated As you can see, mpl::for_each passes default-constructed **value** of each given type into function object. If type is not default-constructible or default-construction is costly or does not have sense in such context, then you can just wrap types into some dummy type, like `mpl::for_each<mpl::vector<bool*, string*, Foo*>>` or `mpl::for_each<mpl::vector<dummy<bool>, dummy<string>, dummy<Foo>>>` or use mpl::identity. Plus, you should do appropriate change in `operator()`.  Or you can implement your version of for_each, which would pass types as template type arguments only.

Answer (score 1):

This uses variadic templates to achieve that:

```
template<typename T>
void do_test(){
   // do the actual testing here, for type T
}

template<typename T>
void test_vectors() {
    do_test<T>();
}

template<typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
void test_vectors() { 
    do_test<T>();
    test_vectors<Head, Tail...>();
}
```

Demo [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yOEFa%240).

Comment: It is possible to do [without recursion](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yOEFa$11): auto &&t={(do_test<Ts>(),0)...};

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do something that works, but isn't very beautiful and works only with default-costructable types:

```
void loop() {
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void loop(T t, Args... args) {
    cerr << "work with " << typeid(T).name() << endl;
    loop(args...);
}
int main() {
    loop(int(), char(), vector<int>(), string());
}
```

Comment: Check botton of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15869682/1762344) - I have second approach based on variadic templates - it doesn't require default-constructability